# How I get to the top of the tower of Winterhold without being the Arch-Mage?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

The Arch-Mage is up there because of a dragon attack.  How do I get up there? I am in the first quest, [Under Saarthal](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Under_Saarthal). I am playing on the Xbox 360.

Comment: what stage of the quest are you at?  The last stage asks you to talk to the archmage so you should have permission to enter his tower.

Comment: Can't you go through the [`Hall of Attainment`](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Hall_of_Attainment)? Head upstairs?

Comment: Please I need help I already pass all the missions and the college of winterhold is the only one left

Comment: Are you on PC? Console commands might help.

Comment: Can you load an earlier save? If you go do something else for a while, then you shouldn't have to deal with the dragon attack.

Comment: Makes me miss [Levitate](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Morrowind:Levitate)

Answer (score 3):

If you're in the part of the [Under Saarthal](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Under_Saarthal) quest where you are asked to meet with the Arch-Mage, [Savos Aren](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Savos_Aren), then just go to the [Arch-Mage's Quarters](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Arch-Mage%27s_Quarters) (first door to the left upon entering the [Hall of the Elements](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Hall_of_the_Elements) [the training chamber]), which should now be unlocked.

If for some weird reason, Savos Aren is not there, like due to the dragon attack you mentioned, then kill the dragon who is attacking, which should make Savos Aren return to his original routine. Then use the wait function and check if Savos Aren walks back to the Arch-Mage's Quarters.

Comment: I already kill the dragon but Savos Avren is still upstairs and is the only place in the entire college were I can't go

Comment: @Jerry Have you tried waiting inside the Arch-Mage's Quarters? Try waiting for a day or two in there.

Comment: Yes i already tríed the arch mage is not gonna move